# I need to delete the nested loops and use string concatenation

Tags: php

```
<?php
echo "How much stacks do you want?\n";
$a = readline("");
$x1 = "*";

    //Inner Loop
for ($x = 1; $x <= $a; $x++) {
    //Outer loop
        for ($z = 1; $z <= $x; $z++) {
            echo "*";
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
?>
```

I need to stop making use of the nested loops in this code, and change it to string concatenation.
It is an php script for making a pyramid using a readline.

Comment: _Side note:_ "Outer loop" = the first loop containing the other loops. "Inner loop" = The loop that's inside the outer loop. You have it backwards in your code (the comments)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?php
echo "How much stacks do you want?\n";
$a = readline("");
$x1 = "*";

for ($x = 1; $x <= $a; $x++) {
    echo $x1 . "\n";
    $x1 .= '*';
}
```